# Open() Requires Integer?

Tags: python, syntax, flags, python-3.7

The code reads:

```
file=open('cake.txt','w')
```

The following shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
open('cake.txt','w')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

This syntax worked perfectly on the 3.6 version, now that i upgraded to 3.7 it doesn't. What is happening here? The "cake.txt' file doesn't exist by the way.

The python documents are not helping either.

Comment: Have you defined a function called `open`?

Comment: Are you running this in an interactive session? Is it possible that you did a `def open(…)` earlier, or a `from <something> import *` not realizing there was a `something.open` to import? (Either one of these can be tested, and fixed, by just doing `del open`.)

Comment: The book says you just call open(name,mode) and works.
I used from os import * and it still did the same error.
And then i switched to import os and worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that is that, if you do:

```
from os import *
```

You've replaced [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open) with [`os.open`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.open). `flags` would be `int` where you've tried to pass `mode`, but really probably not the function you wanted.

There is a whole plethora of [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/search.html?q=open) functions and method. Better be careful with wild card imports (in general).

(Esp. if in interactive sessions) you can also type `help(open)` which should give you a good idea about what `open` are you dealing with.

---

*Community wiki answer reflective of the comments... feel free to improve.*